# How to disable large title shrink when scrolling

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, large-title

I want to use large title navigation bar. But navigation bar is getting smaller when I scroll screen. How can I disable shrink to NavigationBar.

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem:

Make sure there is no scrollview at the top of your view hierarchy. If you have scrollView(TableView, CollectionView) it is shrink.

[image]